# How to create a little PHP script that will calculate some items based on portion/price?

Tags: php, database

I'd like to write a script in PHP, that will do a little math for me.

It should complete the following tasks:

**Example**

Let's say you have an online shop for fruit juice.
You want to

1. save several juices to the the database (think: orange juice, lemon juice, apple juice).
2. You also want to save these juices with portion and price (e.g. 100ml / 2,50 USD).
3. You want to mix/combine different juices and get the total amount of ml/ USD.

**If we add this up:**

Orange juice: 100ml / 2,50 USD | I'll take 50ml = 1,25 USD.

Apple Juice:  100ml / 1,50 USD | I'll take 10ml = 0,15 USD.

**Total juice mix: 60ml = 1,40 USD.**

So far so good.
I've wrote the following code:

```
<?php
  function devide() {
  $portion = 100;         //variable for ml    
  $price = 2.50;          //variable for price
  $portionNew = 50;       //value for new portion put into total mix
    if($portionNew > 0) {
      echo ($price / 100 * $portionNew);  //calculates price of new portion
    } 
  }
      echo "Total Juice" . (" = ");  
      echo devide() . (" USD") ;
?>
```

This code only calculates the price of the portion you take out of one juice.
If you take 30ml out of 100ml juice, it will echo the price.

**These are my questions:**

1. How do I make this script echo no only the new price but the new portion as well (`$portionNew`)?
2. Is a function the right thing to begin with regarding what I want the final script to do? Or should I consider an Object or Array instead?
3. How should I go on with this script, so that it will add multiple (`$portionNews/ $price`) to tell me the final price and portion of my total juice mix?

Comment: for USD you want to use `.` instead of `,` for your decimal place, ie `0.15 USD`

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply add something like `echo 'Portion: '.$portionNew` to your `devide` function. (I believe you probably want to call it `divide`?)
2. You could create a `Juice` class, but I think that'd be overkill in this case. I'd probably stick with an array to store the juices and their prices and a function to mix multiple juices.
3. You could create a function that mixes juices. You would specify a variable that contains the current price and portion in the mix, the type and the amount of juice to add, and it would return a value representing the new price and amount of juice in the mix.

If you want to store the juices in an array, it could look like this:

```
// In this case, we have an array that maps the juice type to a price (in cents
// per 100 ml).
$juices = array(
    'orange' => 250,
    'apple' => 150
);

// If you decide you need to store more information about a juice, you can change
// this array to map a juice type to another associative array that contains the
// price and your additional information.
// Beware: if you use this, you have to change the mixJuices function to access
// a juice's "price" value:
//     $pricePerLiter = $juices[$juiceType]['price'] * 10;
$juices = array(
    'orange' => array(
        'price' => 250,
        'color' => 'orange'
    ),
    'apple' => array(
        'price' => 150,
        'color' => 'yellow'
    )
);
```

Notice that I'm setting the price in cents instead of dollars. By doing this, I avoid using floats and all the issues associated with them while calculating prices (see [the red notice on floating point precision in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php))

The function to mix juices could look like this:

```
// The function needs to know what's currently in the mix, which is why it's
// taking the $currentMix as a parameter. Also, it needs to know about all the
// available juices, which is why it's taking the $juices as another parameter.
// A mix is represented by an associative array that contains the current amount
// of juice in the mix (identified by "portion") and the current price
// (identified by "price"). Note that you need to pass the $juices array I
// defined earlier, so it can access the different types of juices and their 
// prices.
function mixJuices($currentMix, $juices, $juiceType, $juicePortion)
{
    $pricePerLiter = $juices[$juiceType] * 10;
    $price = $pricePerLiter * $juicePortion / 1000;
    $currentMix['portion'] = $currentMix['portion'] + $juicePortion;
    $currentMix['price'] = $currentMix['price'] + $price;
    return $currentMix;
}
```

This function could also have been written to use a global `$mix` variable. If you did that, you wouldn't need to pass the $currentMix to the function. However, you'd also lose the ability to create multiple mixes at the same time (because all calls to that modified `mixJuices` function would modify the same, global mix).

You can the function I defined above like this:

```
// At the beginning, there's no juice at all, so it doesn't cost anything (yet)
$mix = array('portion' => 0, 'price' => 0);

// Let's mix some juice in
$mix = mixJuices($mix, $juices, 'apple', 500);
$mix = mixJuices($mix, $juices, 'orange', 250);

// Print the amount of juice and the price
// The price is divided by 100 so we can display it in dollars instead of cents
echo sprintf('%d milliliters of this juice mix will cost %.2f USD.',
    $mix['portion'], $mix['price'] / 100);
```

---

This approach allows you to do all sorts of interesting things.

Say you have two customers who want to order a juice mix. You can easily mix multiple juices at the same type by creating two different `$mix` arrays:

```
// Process customer 1's order
$mixCustomer1 = array('portion' => 0, 'price' => 0);
$mixCustomer1 = mixJuices($mixCustomer1, $juices, 'apple', 250);
$mixCustomer1 = mixJuices($mixCustomer1, $juices, 'orange', 250);
echo sprintf('%d milliliters of this juice mix will cost %.2f USD.',
    $mixCustomer1['portion'], $mixCustomer1['price'] / 100);
// 500 milliliters of this juice mix will cost 10.00 USD.

// Process customer 2's order
$mixCustomer2 = array('portion' => 0, 'price' => 0);
$mixCustomer2 = mixJuices($mixCustomer2, $juices, 'apple', 150);
$mixCustomer2 = mixJuices($mixCustomer2, $juices, 'orange', 350);
echo sprintf('%d milliliters of this juice mix will cost %.2f USD.',
    $mixCustomer2['portion'], $mixCustomer2['price'] / 100);
// 500 milliliters of this juice mix will cost 11.00 USD.
```

Now let's say that customer 2 has some sort of voucher which gets him 20% off any juice:

```
// Apply the discount
$discountedJuices = array_map(function($price) { return (1 - 0.2) * $price; }, $juices);

// Process customer 2's order
$mixCustomer2 = array('portion' => 0, 'price' => 0);
$mixCustomer2 = mixJuices($mixCustomer2, $discountedJuices, 'apple', 150);
$mixCustomer2 = mixJuices($mixCustomer2, $discountedJuices, 'orange', 350);
echo sprintf('%d milliliters of this juice mix will cost %.2f USD.',
    $mixCustomer2['portion'], $mixCustomer2['price'] / 100);
// 500 milliliters of this juice mix will cost 8.80 USD.
```

Comment: Man I don't even know how to thank you! You must have taken quite some effort to write all this down. That's just great and very appreciated. Little note btw: as for typos like (devide/divide) I am not a native speaker so I get stuff confused sometimes :) 

**I still have quite some questions left:**

1) I would like to add more information to my juices like say nutrition. At the first array $juices you said that this could be archived by mapping a juice type to another array. I googled that but I can't seem to get it right. Could you explain further here?

Comment: *Question 2:* is $mix an associative Array? It seems very complex to me and I don't understand the syntax...especially within the parentheses(). I read it like: $var = name($var, $array, $key, newValue); . But why for example is there $var a 2nd time within the parantheses?

Comment: Last but not least I'd like to thank you for teaching me about "sprint". I didn't know it before...google it and understand it! Great work! thx

Comment: Regarding question 1: Basically, instead of saying `'orange' => 250` (juice => price), you would do `'orange' => array('price' => 250, 'color' => 'orange')` (juice => information array). I added an example of this to my answer. Regarding question 2: Yes, `$mix` is an associative array. `mixJuices` takes an array that contains information about the current mix, and returns an array of the same type that contains information about the new mix. That is why you pass the current `$mix` (so it knows what's in the mix) and assign the result to `$mix` (so you can remember what was added to the mix).